# IIS10 Redirect based on country

Tags: iis-10

I have URL rewrite installed in IIS and potentially that could be used but I'm trying to figure out how I could redirect a website to a different domain (not hosted by me) depending on the country the visitor is from.

I have a brand website for the United states and all visitors in the US & CA should arrive at my site. But if their from any other country they should be redirected to the parent website that's on a different domain not hosted by me.

How can this be done in IIS10, or via the URL Rewrite module for IIS?

Comment: Without coding and a suitable IP-to-Geo API, that's impossible on any web server.

Comment: Hi Lex, any links you can share that I can check out?

Comment: You should use a search engine to dig further into such topics. Commercial solutions are out there, such as [this](https://en.ipip.net/).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching on how to do something similar, this site was helpful. Will need to build into a custom utility but the concept is sound.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28363/How-to-convert-IP-address-to-country-name
https://lite.ip2location.com/